# How to download files on AWS Cloud 9?

Tags: aws-cloud9

I am following the Ruby on Rails tutorial. In chapter 6, [the tutorial tells me to download the development.sqlite3 database file](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#fig-sqlite_download), but it doesn't seem possible with AWS Cloud 9. The "Download" option does not appear in the menu. How can I download this file?

Comment: A more detailed description of your problem and a link to the tutorial would help people better understand your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! 
The link below illustrates how I should download a file. But when using AWS cloud 9, it doesn't give me the option. When I right click the file in the file tree, it reads (from top down) open, run, preview, refresh, rename..etc. 

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#fig-sqlite_download

Comment: AWS Cloud 9 has restored the file download feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the file download feature has been removed from the AWS version of Cloud 9.  The good news is that there is a workaround.  Right-click on the filename and select "preview".  Depending on the file extension, selecting "preview" seems to do one of two things:

1. It downloads the file, which is what you want.  It also opens it up in a Cloud 9 tab which you can close.
2. It opens the file up in a Cloud 9 tab without downloading.  At this point, you can:

   a. Select the Cloud 9 tab.

   b. Click the [image: icon] icon to display the contents of the Cloud 9 tab in a separate browser tab.

   c. Once you have the item in a browser tab, you can use your browser to save the file locally.

This is not the cleanest solution, but it should work accomplish your goal.

**Update:**
According to [this post on the AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=818108&#818108) (AWS login required), the file download feature is not included in the AWS version of Cloud 9. You may want to [use your legacy Cloud 9 account](https://c9.io/login) if you need this feature.

**Update 2:** It appears AWS Cloud 9 has restored the File Download feature.  And there was much rejoicing.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this post on AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=820706&tstart=0#820706) the **Download feature is back now**!